# Custom Button Shape (substract shapes)

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to create a custom button where a circular shape is cut out from a rectangular button, see mockup.

[image: Mockup]

I already looked into the `Outline` class but it doesn't provide subtraction, only rects and ovals, no combination of them.
Also, I thought of setting `android:background` to a custom drawable but I couldn't succeed. The drawable consisted of a `layer-list` with a colored rect and a white oval but the oval was always placed at a different position depending on the device's resolution.

Do I really have to go through the pain of creating my own `View` class? That seems to be an overkill for this rather simple task, doesn't it?

PS: Concerning usability, I know that buttons close to each other aren't user-friendly, but this problem doesn't arise in my real scenario, only in this mockup.

Comment: no custom `View`, instead create a custom `Drawable` class

Comment: @pskink I mentioned that I tried a custom drawable.xml but I couldn't figure out how to position the circle at a fixed size and fixed position for all resolutions.

Comment: i didnt say custom drawable.xml, i said: custom `Drawable` class (`android.graphics.drawable.Drawable`)

Comment: @pskink Still I don't know how to combine different shapes in such a class, let alone how to fix position and size of the circle. So the same restrictions apply to the _class_ as to the XML version I tried, don't they?

Comment: when using xml you have fixed design: the only thing you can do are multiple xml files in different configuration related folders, with custom `Drawable` you have a freedom to draw whatever you like in 100% dynamic way

Comment: @pskink That's not correct. With the `list-layer` tag you can draw multiple basic shapes on top of each other. My problem is that I cannot fix the shapes resolution-independently, as I wrote. Could you demonstrate how the class could help me?

Comment: yes, "basic shapes" is a keyword here, you cannot draw something like [this](http://pasteboard.co/bHYGXCo4T.png) for example